# Server Error i / Application

Tags: c#, .net

I have in my production environment a compiled version and I create a new `aspx` but when I tried to call the web page is showing a message error (see "Problem Production Environment" below).

How can I find a way to call the new web page in my production environment?, knowing that I can not compile the web application from dev environment (see "Details" below).

Please,  your collaboration to find a solution.

Thanks

---

Details.
1. I want to say that I can not compile and deploy the version from dev environment because this version is different vs production environment.

2. In `dev` environment, the new web page works. I setup in the controller file and from the Menu to call the web page.

### //new request - Controller.cs public ActionResult summary() { return View(); }

`Menu.ascx` file
...
customer/summary"                     title=" Summary"> Summary

---

**Problem Production Environment.**

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
Requested URL: /customer/summary
```

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2558.0

Comment: Missing some important details I believe.
What is different between your dev/prod environment?

Comment: How are you migrating changes from dev to prod? Are you sure that the changes are available in prod version of the code? There are no merge issues? What is you host the production deployable to dev environment? Does it work fine?

Comment: Hi ZCharles and Chetan,  when the change is over existing pages only I have one way and is write c# code in the same ASPX.  I know that is a bad idea but when I join in this job who developed this web application not create a test environment and the developer's group that supported the application never try to decompile and create dev/test environment or try to merge earlier versions when they received the project (e.g. 2012).

Comment: ...continuing...   "ZCharlkes and Chetan" ........   --> Now, really I don't know how many changes can exist, probability some pages but to make this work I need check aspx by aspx, .js , .dll "size" and run and compare dev/test vs prod.  (e.g. diff in GUI, missing fields,etc).   Could you help How can I fix this problem to call the new aspx?